# Accessing a variable inside a javascript while web page is loading

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium-webdriver

I was doing some selenium test case writing on c#.

I have faced  an issue when capturing a value on the web page.
Actual i don't wont to capture the value on the web page, because it is rounded to 5 decimal pints.
SO what i need is to capture the row value before it rounded.

so the Row value is stored in a javascript array  as on the below image.

[image]

so is there any way to get the values on array list at the java script and assert that value from the c# code with my expected value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
IWebDriver driver; 
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string arrayValue= (string)js.ExecuteScript("return yourArray[0]");
```

You can define some JavaScript code in the ExecuteScript function to make the array available

Comment: Thanks TGH ,unfortunate there is an exception "{Cannot evaluate expression because debugging information has been optimized away .}"

Comment: {"Modal dialog present"}

Comment: my code looks like this :    'code'                                                         IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            string arrayValue = (string)js.ExecuteScript("actualList[2]");'code'

Comment: you can try to wrap the array in a function and call the function in the ExecuteScript block.